# React Hooks onClick in list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a list and I wanna set 'onClick' function which click to each item then show detail of item. 
But my function returned undefine object
I used react hooks and functional component

here is my code

```
 var listItem = data.map((i, index) => (<Item key={index}
    isRead={i['isRead']}
    image={i['image']}
    content={i['content']}
    time={i['time']}
    onClick={(i) => console.log('Click to',i.content)}
></Item>));
return (
    <div className="Conversation">
        <div className="ScrollDiv">
            {listItem}
        </div>

    </div>
);
```

[result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbRsi.png)

Answer (score 3):

The `i` parameter in the callback function represents the event that gets passed to the callback, and by naming that variable `i` you prevent the callback from using `i` from the outer scope.

You need to remove the `i` parameter of the callback function :

```js
onClick={() => console.log('Click to',i.content)}
```

or rename it to something else :

```js
onClick={(event) => console.log('Click to',i.content)}
```